# Fetching from a simple Node.js Express app after deployment

Tags: node.js, express, fetch

I've made a very basic node express app that returns some text.

```
let express = require('express');
let cors = require('cors');

let app = express();
let text = 'hello World'

app.use(cors());

app.get('/data', function(req, res){
  res.send(text);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

I'm trying to fetch data from it in my main.js with this:

```
// let url = 'http://localhost:3000/data'; -- this runs locally
let url = 'what_to_put_in_this_after_its_deployed';


let textNode = document.getElementById('text');

let button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = () => {
    $.get(url, {}, function(data){

        console.log(data);
        textNode.innerHTML = data;

   });
}
```

I run it locally and it works with localhost:3000. 
I deploy it on a2hosting, using Setup Node.js App, it's running, but I can't find the url to fetch from. I've tried my shared hosting ip, lets say it's 10.10.11.11:3000/data, I've tried http://mywebsite.com/data . 
I have access to a terminal on the host, is there a way to see what address to fetch from?

Comment: Presumably you're using a virtual private server on your hosting service. You haven't told us what they set up for you when you install a node app. Maybe they put your app behind a so-called reverse proxy server. If that's the case, try `https://mywebsite.com/data`.  At any rate, **ask them about this, not us.**

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Yes I've tried `https://mywebsite.com/data` and I have been talking to their tech support, but they're not sure. I was asking here to see if there's a way to use the terminal on my hosted server to see what node servers are running

Comment: `ps axuww | grep nodejs` should show you any running node programs, `netstat | grep 3000` should show you something if port 3000 is listening. IF you're on Linux or FreeBSD.